# how to fix Module 'GoogleMobileAds' not found error on IOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am getting this error with a react native project , I followed some steps 
that I have found after making my searches but I am still having the same error :

> Module 'GoogleMobileAds' not found

Please see my screenshoots to see my setting on xcode .

**Image 1**

[image]

and this another from my setting

**Image 2**

[image]

My Xcode Version --> 10.0